# How to setup custom filename while using Wizard Dialog Eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

How to setup custom filename while using Wizard Dialog eclipse RCP?

This is my source code:

```java
WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(shell, wizard);

dialog.create();
```

[image: Have look here]

Comment: What do you mean by 'default file name'? [edit] your question and add more details.

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: Please have a look over link. Once this popup will come then filename will have default name .It should not be null or empty.

Comment: That doesn't help much. Again what do you mean by 'default file name' - where is the default supposed to come from? The current selection?

Comment: @greg-449 ,  Suppose I want to save any file then this popup will come and user simply enter name and click on ok . Right ! Now What I want ? any default value will come there like Default or else help to user save file without enter any name. I Think now you got the point well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a default for the file name in the code displaying the wizard you can give that to your wizard before creating the dialog.

Something like:

```java
String defaultFileName = ...... get from somewhere ....

IWizard wizard = new MyWizard(defaultFileName);

WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(shell, wizard);

dialog.create();
```

Your `MyWizard` constructor can save the default file name and give it to the WizardPages in the wizard that need it.